# Formatting JSON in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I want to return a JSON from ASP.NET MVC ActionResult type method that looks something like this:

```
{
     success: true,
     users: [
    {id: 1, FileName: 'Text22'},
    {id: 2, FileName: 'Text23'}
    ]
}
```

How would I format it? Right now I have something like this

```
Return Json(New With {Key .success = "true", Key .users = responseJsonString}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Edit: I am using VB.NET but answers in C# are fine too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer using ViewModels, rather than manually constructing complex JSON responses. It ensures consistency against all methods that return the data, and is easier to work with strongly typed properties IMHO.

```
public class Response
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then just:

```
Response response = new Response();
response.Success = true;
// populate the rest of the data

return Json(response);
```

This also has the advantage of letting you use a base class for every response, if there's common data like a success status, or error messages.

```
public class ResponseBase
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class UserResponse : ResponseBase
{ 
    IENumerable<User> Users { get; set }
}
```

Now, if you have an error:

```
return Json(new ResponseBase() { Success = false, Message = "your error" });
```

or if it succeeds

```
return Json(new UserResponse() { Success = true, Users = users });
```

If you want to manually craft the JSON, then just:

```
return Json(new { success = true, users = new[] { new { id = 1, Name = "Alice"}, new { id = 2, Name = "Bob"} } });
```

Answer (score 1):

in C#

```
return Json(new
    {
        success = true,
        users = new[]
            {
                new {id = 1, FileName = "Text22"}, new {id = 2, FileName = "Text23"}
            }
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

returns

{"success":true,"users":[{"id":1,"FileName":"Text22"},{"id":2,"FileName":"Text23"}]}